# Algebra (sequence & series): $\sum_{r=1}^{n}[rx]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation

How to find summation of $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}[rx]$ and  $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}\left\{rx\right\}$? (where [ ] is greatest integer function & { } is fractional part)

Comment: Do x have to be rational number or it can be any real number?

Comment: It can be any real number

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=k+e$ where $k = [x]$ and $0\leq e <1$.  Let $p$ be the integer such that $\frac{p}{n} \leq e < \frac{p+1}{n}.$  Then

$$\sum_{r=1}^n [rx] = \sum_{r=1}^n rk + \sum_{r=1}^n [re] =k\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \sum_{r=1}^n [re].$$

For the last sum, $[re]$ will take the value $0$ exactly $[n/p]$-times.  Then it will take the value $1$ the same number of times, etc., up to the value $p$.  So the last sum is the same as

$$ \left[\frac{n}{p}\right] \sum_{j=1}^p j = \left[\frac{n}{p}\right]\frac{p(p+1)}{2}.$$

Putting them together gives:

$$\sum_{r=1}^n [rx] =[x]\frac{n(n+1)}{2} +\left[\frac{n}{p}\right]\frac{p(p+1)}{2}.$$

The other sum can be obtained by subtracting this from $\sum rx.$